# Golang error handling

Tags: go

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    // infinite loop
    for {

        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {

            conn, err := opentsdb.OpenConnection()

            if err {
                time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I need Program will execute from the beginning if an error block occur.

How to handle it?

Comment: You're correct-- your for loop will run forever. What's the requirement? Do you want the program to exit if there's an error? The question is unclear about what you want to do. "Handle it" can mean a variety of things.

Answer (score 7):

Using `goto` is a common way to handle error flows in a nested loop

```
func main() {
RESTART:
    for {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            conn, err := opentsdb.OpenConnection()
            if err {
                time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
                goto RESTART
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to restart the outer loop, and there's nothing between the `RESTART` label and the `for` loop, you can use `continue RESTART` to continue the loop at the `RESTART` label. In this simple case, just using `break` will continue the outer loop as well.

Comment: @icza: yes, that works here too. I just assumed such a trivial example probably was missing other logic in there, otherwise you could also just `break` here too.